# Adding an IF to a COLUMNTOCHECK var

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to add an "if" statement to my var COLUMNTOCHECK line so that it checks the column for a specific value, not just that something is in the cell. This is my script so far. I want to make it so that the timestamp only activates if the afformentioned column(s) contain the words "UC Phone". I want it to check if this is true in columns 5, 6, or 7.

```
var COLUMNTOCHECK = 5;

var DATETIMELOCATION = [0,13];

var SHEETNAME = ('December 17, 2018')

function check() {

  return true;
}

function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  if( sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME ) { 
    var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();

    if( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK)
    { 
      var dateTimeCell = selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION[0],DATETIMELOCATION[1]);
      dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());

      }
  }
}
```

I'm pretty new to scripting in Google Sheets, so I have been working off of a code I found scouring the web.

Answer (score 0):

I know the tutorial that you've used as the basis for this code. It's quite useful but it also has the effect of diving in at the deep end.

Your OnEdit(e) function is known as a "Simple" trigger.
The "e" parameter enables you to capture and use seven pieces of information about the edit event. There's a list of the information [here in Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit).
I've created a Logger.log entry for each value so you can see the information returned.

```
function onEdit(e) {
    // so_53748818
    // Setup spreadsheet and target sheet
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

    // setup some variables
    var SHEETNAME = ('53748818');
    var COLUMNTOCHECK = 5;
    var valuetocheck = "UC Phone";
    var DATETIMELOCATION = [0, 13];
    var counter = 0;

    // get and display the (e) event information
    var debug_e = {
        authMode: e.authMode,
        range: e.range.getA1Notation(),
        source: e.source.getId(),
        user: e.user,
        value: e.value,
        oldValue: e.oldValue
    };
    Logger.log("AuthMode: " + debug_e.authMode);// DEBUG
    Logger.log("Range: " + debug_e.range);// DEBUG
    Logger.log("Source: " + debug_e.source);// DEBUG
    Logger.log("User: " + debug_e.user);// DEBUG
    Logger.log("user email" + debug_e.user.getEmail());// DEBUG
    Logger.log("Value: " + debug_e.value);// DEBUG
    Logger.log("Old value: " + debug_e.oldValue);// DEBUG
    //Logger.log("AuthMode: "+debug_e.authMode+", Range: "+debug_e.range+", source: "+debug_e.source+", user: "+debug_e.user+", value: "+debug_e.value+", old value: "+debug_e.oldValue);// DEBUG


    // get the row number
    var editRow = e.range.getRow();
    Logger.log("the Row edited was " + editRow);// DEBUG

    // Assumes that the edit field is in Column D
    var checkrange = sheet.getRange(editRow, COLUMNTOCHECK, 1, 3)
    Logger.log("checkrange = " + checkrange.getA1Notation());// DEBUG
    var checkvalues = checkrange.getValues();

    // loop through the values in columns E, F & G
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        Logger.log("i: " + i + ", value: " + checkvalues[0][i]);// DEBUG
        if (checkvalues[0][i] == valuetocheck) {
          counter = counter + 1; // add one to the counter for each value matched
        }
    }
    if (counter == 3) { // if counter is 3, then all the cells contained the value
        Logger.log(" the counter is " + counter + ", so the date is inserted in column 13 (Q)");// DEBUG
        var dateTimeCell = e.range.offset(DATETIMELOCATION[0], DATETIMELOCATION[1]);
        dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
    } else { // the else is not strictly required, but included so that the counter value can be displayed for debug purposes.
        Logger.log(" the counter is " + counter + ", so the date is NOT inserted in column 13 (Q)");// DEBUG
    }

}
```